# Understanding Python's Callback(ExitStack) example

Tags: python

I am trying to understand the examples for replacing the use of try-finally and flag variables in [Python's documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html?highlight=contextmanager#replacing-any-use-of-try-finally-and-flag-variables)

According to the documentation instead of:

```
cleanup_needed = True
try:
    result = perform_operation()
    if result:
        cleanup_needed = False
finally:
    if cleanup_needed:
        cleanup_resources()
```

we could use a small `ExitStack`-based helper class `Callback` like this (I added the `perform_operation` and `cleanup_resources` function):

```
from contextlib import ExitStack

class Callback(ExitStack):
    def __init__(self, callback, /, *args, **kwds):
        super(Callback, self).__init__()
        self.callback(callback, *args, **kwds)
    def cancel(self):
        self.pop_all()

def perform_operation():
    return False

def cleanup_resources():
    print("Cleaning up resources")

with Callback(cleanup_resources) as cb:
    result = perform_operation()
    if result:
        cb.cancel()
```

I think the code simulates the exceptional case, where the `perform_operation()` did not run smoothly and a cleanup is needed (`perform_operation()` returned `False`). The Callback class magically takes care of the running the `cleanup_resources()` function (I can't quite understand why, by the way).

Then I simulated the normal case, where everything runs smoothly and no cleanup is needed, I *changed the code* to make `perform_operation()` return `True` instead. In this case, however, the `cleanup_resources` function also runs and the code errors out:

```
$ python minimal.py
Cleaning up resources
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "minimal.py", line 26, in <module>
    cb.cancel()
  File "minimal.py", line 12, in cancel
    self.pop_all()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\claw\lib\contextlib.py", line 390, in pop_all
    new_stack = type(self)()
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'callback'
```

Can you explain what exactly is going on here and how this whole ExitStack and callack stuff works?